# A Variable in JS is not deleted but here is no error?

Tags: javascript

I have a variable. `var variable;` It is `variable="Hello World";`. Now, without using var and deleting it:

```js
document.write(myVar);
delete myVar;
console.log("This should be an error because myVar has been deleted: ");
console.log(myVar);
```

```html
<!--This is my module-->
<script>
  myVar = "Hello";
</script>
```

But with `'use strict';`, there is no error with delete, and no error even though it cannot delete a var?

```js
console.log("My Code Is Running");
delete myVar; 
if (!myVar){
document.write("Var Has Been Deleted");
}
console.log("My Code Is Done");

// Why does it not write "Var Has Been Deleted"?
// There is no 'use strict' to stop the delete.
```

```html
<script>
'use strict';
var myVar = "Hello World";
</script>
```

What is happening?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `"use strict"` should be applied to the code performing `delete`, not the code declaring the variable.

Comment: `delete myVar` is a syntax error in strict mode.

Comment: Put `"use strict"` in the JavaScript box of the Stack Snippet, not the HTML box.

Comment: `"use strict"` is a directive with the same sort of scope as a variable - it'll only be in force inside the block/script that you define it in, not everywhere.